# How to edit NHibernate Junction using QueryOver?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

**Context:**

I have a method to create a long `Conjunction`:

```
public static Conjunction GetLongConjunction() 
{
    Conjunction conjunction = new Conjunction();
    conjunction.Add<Person>(p => p.Id > 0);
    conjunction.Add<Person>(p => p.Age > 18);

    Disjunction disjunction = new Disjunction();
    disjunction.Add<Person>(p => p.Name == "John");
    disjunction.Add<Person>(p => p.Name == "Alice");

    conjunction.Add(disjunction);
    // ...
    return conjunction;
}
```

In another method, I'm using `GetLongConjunction` to get the conjunction:

```
public void AnotherMethod() 
{
    Conjunction newConjunction = GetLongConjunction();
    // ...
}
```

> The problem is: I want to **edit** (or remove) one condition in `newConjunction`.

**What I tried:**

I tried to get the `List<NHibernate.Criterion.ICriterion>` in `criteria` property from `AbstractCriterion` class. `Conjunction` extends it:

```
Conjunction: Junction: AbstractCriterion
```

But `criteria` is a **private** property, and I can't get it.

**Question:**

So, my question is: 
How can I edit a NHibernate Junction? Is that possible?

Thanks!!

Comment: This might be possible, but you may be better off refactoring a bit into multiple methods that exclude the desired conjunction(s)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I can do that, but I think it's possible at least iterate the Conjunction. If we can iterate the Conjunction we can create another modified, and another method will not be necessary.

Comment: Why don't use a collection of expressions, then you can create an extension method to create a conjuntion? `expressionList.ToConjunction()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple, you can use reflection:

```
public void AnotherMethod() 
{
    Conjunction newConjunction = GetLongConjunction();
    IList<ICriterion> criteria = newConjunction.GetCriteria();

    // Add or remove expressions
    // var disjunction = (Disjunction) criteria.Last();
}
```

Using this extension methods:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IList<ICriterion> GetCriteria(this Junction juntion)
    {
        return juntion.GetPrivateFieldValue<IList<ICriterion>>("criteria");
    }
    public static T GetPrivateFieldValue<T>(this object obj, string propName)
    {
        if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        FieldInfo fi = null;
        while (fi == null && t != null)
        {
            fi = t.GetField(propName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            t = t.BaseType;
        }
        if (fi == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("propName", string.Format("Field {0} was not found in Type {1}", propName, obj.GetType().FullName));
        return (T)fi.GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Najera, thanks for answering. Your solution is good, but works only for simple conjunctions that can be constructed with expressions. A conjunction can be constructed with another junctions too. So, if the conjunction have junctions inside it a collection of expressions will not solve the problem. I edited the `GetLongConjunction` method to be more clear.